# Odoo list view with variant data type

Tags: odoo

Is there any way in Odoo to create a list view with inline editing where the data type of the row is variant across rows?

Small example:
Imaging a model with a o2m relation to attributes to this model where each of these attributes should have a name, a type and a value (whereas the value just might be a string with different UI representation depending on type)

Say we would like to have INT, BOOL, STRING and some ENUM datatypes.

I’m searching for a possibility to display all attributes to such a model in a list view (with inline editing if possible) and have each row using it’s own widget depending on the type. I.e. having a checkbox for BOOL, drop down selection field for ENUM etc.

All these widgets already exist in Odoo for whole columns. 
I.e. what I would like to have is something similiar like having a list view with separate  columns for each data type, but in just a single column with dynamic selection of the appropriate widget for each row depending on the attribute type.